# Java serialization and duplicate objects

Tags: java, serialization, duplicates

I have the following setup:

```
public class A {
  private Set<C> cSet;
}

public class B {
  private Set<C> cSet;
}

public class C {}
```

A's and B's cSet might have references to same C instances. I want to serialize A and B such that upon deserialization I don't have duplicate C objects. Will Java know how to do the right thing if I serialize/deserialize it into the same ObjectOutputStream, or might I end up with more C instances than I started out with?

Comment: Interesting question... have you tried serializing/deserializing and check the results?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665567/avoiding-duplicate-objects-in-java-deserialization

Comment: @user1339772, that question is slightly different in that it writes to two different files. In my case I am still writing to one file.

Comment: I hope I am going to run into such a case, and your question will be great reference to me. +rep

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you won't get more instances of `C` than necessary. That's because internally, the [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) registers every ever serialized object in a 'handle table'. So even across multiple invocations of [`writeObject(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject(java.lang.Object)), the same object will never be written twice!

API documentation for [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html):

> (...) Multiple references to a single object are encoded using a reference sharing mechanism so that graphs of objects can be restored to the same shape as when the original was written. (...)

Consider this code (assuming `A`, `B` and `C` are [`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html) and both, `A` and `B` have a non-transient field `c` pointing to an instance of `C`):

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
a.c = c;
b.c = c;

out.writeObject(a); // writes a and c
out.writeObject(b); // writes b and the handle to c
```

Now let's read both objects:

```
A a2 = (A)in.readObject(); // reads a and c
B b2 = (B)in.readObject(); // reads b and handle to c, so b.c points to existing c
// now this is true: a2.c == b2.c
```

This also works if you directly write an object twice, e.g.:

```
A a = new A();
out.writeObject(a); // writes a
out.writeObject(a); // writes handle to a
```

The second `writeObject` will only write the handle, not the object itself. That means when you deserialize the objects again, you won't get two instances of `A`:

```
A a1 = (A)in.readObject(); // reads a
A a2 = (A)in.readObject(); // reads the handle and returns existing a
// now this is true: a1 == a2
```

By calling [`reset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset()), you can clear the 'handle table' so that the stream behaves like newly created.

Note that a `ObjectOutputStream` also offers a method [`writeObjectUnshared(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeUnshared(java.lang.Object)) that always writes an object as a new unique object to the stream.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, he should define a container object referencing to both A and B, and serialize that container, when deserializing everything goes fine, but calling writeObject(a), writeObject(b) shall not work as he wants.

Comment: @isnot2bad code should work until you call `out.reset()`, which clears that handling table.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh yes indeed, its exactly like that! Feel free to copy the code and run it!